# How to insert multiple `product` with multiple other variables in purchase order form

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, mysqli

I have 10 rows of following code in my purchase order form. Where user add value manually

```
<input type="text" name="name[]" />
<input type="text" name="code[]" />
<input type="text" name="rate[]" />
<input type="text" name="tax[]" />
<input type="text" name="amount[]" />
```

In some cases if the purchase order is only for 3 items then the rest of 7 rows will be blank. So how can I create an Insert query to add only filled cell value in Product_purchased table according to the values of their respective rows.

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$code = $_POST['code'];

foreach( $name as $names ) {
print $names ;
}
```

The above code will combine all the names but I want value of a rows in it, an array like

```
array ("name" => Product 1, "code" => P30, "rate" => 1000, "tax" => 12, "amount" => 1120)
```

and then submit it in an Insert query.

Answer (score 2):

```
$output = [];
  for($i=0;$i<count($name);$i++){
      $data['name'] = $name[$i];
      $data['code'] = $code[$i];
      ...

      $output[] = $data;
  }
```

Create a array and iterate all arrays and push.

`$output` will have multi array of all products. looping `$output` to perform insert to database.

Comment: Will it ignore empty input values or do I need to add an if(empty($_POST($name))) if yes then how to add it in the above loop.

Comment: Yes, you need to do empty validations before processing this loop.